# "Install dependencies with pip" exception when deploy flask project to Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask

I was trying to deploy a simple app to heroku using git push heroku master, then I got the following error:

```
$git push heroku master  
Initializing repository, done.  
Counting objects: 14, done.  
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 8.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.  
Total 14 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)  

-----> Python app detected  
-----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.8)  
-----> Installing dependencies with pip  
       Exception:  
       Traceback (most recent call last):  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main  
           status = self.run(options, args)  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 262, in run  
           for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1629, in parse_requirements  
           line, comes_from=comes_from, default_vcs=options.default_vcs if options else None)  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 124, in from_editable  
           prereleases=True)  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__  
           req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse  
           reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements  
           line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")  
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list  
           raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])  
       ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'Flask-origin/HEAD', 'at', '/HEAD')  

       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log  

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app  

To git@heroku.com:still-brook-1028.git  
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)  
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:still-brook-1028.git'
```

I guess there might be some version inconsistence, but cannot figure out which one it is. Here is my requirements.txt:

```
-e git+http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask.git@577581665ce745898c29ca502e0a3aba1f16677e#egg=Flask-origin/HEAD
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.18
Werkzeug==0.9.6
click==2.4
gunicorn==19.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

This is my first post here, so if anything doesn't look good, pls let me know. Thanks a lot~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-origin/HEAD` part from `git+http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask.git@577581665ce745898c29ca502e0a3aba1f16677e#egg=Flask-origin/HEAD`:

```
-e git+http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask.git@577581665ce745898c29ca502e0a3aba1f16677e#egg=Flask
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.18
Werkzeug==0.9.6
click==2.4
gunicorn==19.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

When [using VCS](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support) the text after `#egg=` has to be a valid [requirement specifier](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirement-specifiers), the same format as when specifying packages directly:

> The url suffix "egg=<project name>" is used by pip in it’s dependency logic to identify the project prior to pip downloading and analyzing the metadata.

Comment: Thx a lot! That solved my problem above. However after I removed "-origin/HEAD", updated with git and redo "git push heroku master", it went time out when installing dependencies with pip. I eventually replaced the whole line "git+http..." with 'flask==0.9', then everything went through. Although I still don't understand why I got time out. BTW, actually the requirements.txt at the very beginning was generated using "pip freeze > requirements.txt". Weird that it's not consistent with VCS...

Comment: @wandonye That's weird indeed, per their docs it should be working without a version too. Still, they [recommend to use specific versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#best-practices). Anyway, glad it's solved!

Comment: Pip appends that "-origin/HEAD" when I install from a git http location as well. No idea why. I think it'll break my Heroku when I push.